# How to scrape dynamic content with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, dynamic

Here's my script :

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

import re
import json
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

URLs = ['https://www.frayssinet-joaillier.fr/fr/p/montre-the-longines-legend-diver-l37744302-bdc2']


TypeVendor = []
NameVendor = []
Marques = []
Brands = []
Refs = []
Prices = []
#Carts = []
#Links = []
Links = []


#df = pd.read_csv('testlink4.csv')

n=1

for url in URLs:

    results = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

    TypeVendor.append('Distributeur')

    NameVendor.append('Frayssinet')

    Marques.append('Longines')

    Brands.append(soup.find('span', class_ = 'main-detail__name').text)

    Refs.append(soup.find('span', class_ = 'main-detail__ref').text)

    Prices.append(soup.find('span', class_ = 'prix').text)

    Links.append(url)
```

I understand why it doesn't work, `text` isn't adapted for dynamic content. But I cannot figure it out how to scrape this kind of content. I know if you find where the json data is sotred, yo ucan tweak with it and scrape the data.

But I checked on the google developer tools, on the network tab and I didn't find anything.

Comment: Check [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71826867/14460824) to your last question again. That is the main issue with your actuall one to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `headers` to your request and store your information in a more structured way.

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
URLs = ['https://www.frayssinet-joaillier.fr/fr/p/montre-the-longines-legend-diver-l37744302-bdc2']

data = []
for url in URLs:

    results = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")
    data.append({
        'name': soup.find('span', class_ = 'main-detail__name').get_text(strip=True),
        'brand': soup.find('span', class_ = 'main-detail__marque').get_text(strip=True),
        'ref':soup.find('span', class_ = 'main-detail__ref').get_text(strip=True),
        'price':soup.find('span', {'itemprop':'price'}).get('content'),
        'url':url
    })

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

##### Output

| name | brand | ref | price | url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Montre The Longines Legend Diver L3.774.4.30.2 | Longines | Référence : L3.774.4.30.2 | 2240 | https://www.frayssinet-joaillier.fr/fr/p/montre-the-longines-legend-diver-l37744302-bdc2 |

Answer (score -1):

HedgeHog's solution worked for me. My problem was to scrape the transcript from LinkedIn Learning course lectures; the code is much simpler, but works:

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
sample_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/learning/' + \
'python-for-data-science-essential-training-part-1/' + \
'navigablestring-objects'

results = requests.get(sample_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")
transcript_div = soup.find("div", attrs={'class': 'transcripts__copy'})
s = list(transcript_div.stripped_strings)[1]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35471920)